# Camel: pollEnrich and access to the Exchange

Tags: java, apache-camel, integration-patterns

I have this route

```
from(URI_WEBSERVICE)
.convertBodyTo(Entrada.class)
.process(new ProcessorTratarWS()) 
.pollEnrich("ftp://10.100.8.2/entradaCamel?username=USER&password=PASSWORD&delete=true&fileName=${property.archivoRespuesta}", timeOut, new EstrategiaConfirmacion())
.to(WS_RESPONDER)
```

In **ProcessorTratarWS()** I set the value of property.archivoRespuesta and is the name of the file that the pollEnrich should donwload.

But, documentation says that "**PollEnrich does not have access to the Exchange**". It means the PollEnrich can't read the value of ${property.archivoRespuesta}

Are there some alternative ways to do in Camel the same thing I'm trying?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html

> ...
>   Instead of using enrich you can use Recipient List and have dynamic
>   endpoints and define an AggregationStrategy on the Recipient List
>   which then would work as a enrich would do. ...

try something like:

```
from(URI_WEBSERVICE)
.convertBodyTo(Entrada.class)
.process(new ProcessorTratarWS()) 
.recipientList(simple("ftp://10.100.8.2/entradaCamel?username=USER&password=PASSWORD&delete=true&fileName=${property.archivoRespuesta}")).aggregationStrategy(new EstrategiaConfirmacion())
.to(WS_RESPONDER)
```

Edit:

The above code is to save file in FTP server.
If you want to poll file from the FTP server you can try

```
        from(URI_WEBSERVICE)
            .convertBodyTo(Entrada.class)
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    // logic of ProcessorTratarWS goes here
                    ConsumerTemplate consumer=exchange.getContext().createConsumerTemplate();
                    String filename=exchange.getProperty("archivoRespuesta",String.class);                  
                    Object file=consumer.receiveBody("ftp://10.100.8.2/entradaCamel?username=USER&password=PASSWORD&delete=true&fileName="+filename,timeOut);
                    // logic of EstrategiaConfirmacion goes here
            }

        })
        .to(WS_RESPONDER);
```

Disclaimer: I have not used [polling consumer](http://camel.apache.org/polling-consumer.html) much and there could be more elegant/efficient solution

Comment: Argh! So confusing! How do I tell to the recipentList that I want retrieve the file and not write the file?

Comment: Finally I understood your question :). Please check my updated answer

Comment: Thanks! It works! So that is how you use the ConsumerTemplate. If you visit Chile, call me... I owe you a beer...

Answer (score 0):

You can use "simple" expression
also use "exchangeProperty" instead of "property" in the string

```
from(URI_WEBSERVICE)
.convertBodyTo(Entrada.class)
.process(new ProcessorTratarWS()) 
.pollEnrich().simple("ftp://10.100.8.2/entradaCamel?username=USER&password=PASSWORD&delete=true&fileName=${exchangeProperty.archivoRespuesta}")
.timeout(timeOut)
.aggregationStrategy(new EstrategiaConfirmacion())
.to(WS_RESPONDER)
```